# Textures inverts in animation

Tags: animation, texturing, drivers

I am new to Blender and got the task from my teacher to create a driving vehicle.

Now I am having a problem with the rotating wheels. When they are rotating, somehow the textures are inverting. So black becomes white. I do not know why and couldn´t find a solution on the internet.

So normally it looks so:
[image]

After a few frames it looks so:
[image]

I am using an Image Texture as well as an Normal Map Vector. I am also aligning the texture in the UV Editor.

Thank you for any help.